# Express Session Not Persisting Between Requests

Tags: express, express-session

I'm having problems with `express-session`. Session data is not persisting between requests.

As you can see in the code below the `/join` route sets some session properties, but when the `/surveys` route is hit the session data is not available. `req.session.loggedIn` returns `undefined` in the `/surveys` route.

```
require('dotenv').config()

const cors = require('cors')
const express = require('express')
const open = require('amqplib').connect(process.env.RABBIT_SERVER)
const session = require('express-session')
const subscribeValidator = require('./src/validators/subscribe')
const { validationResult } = require('express-validator/check')

const app = express()

app.set('trust proxy', 1)
app.use(session({
  name: 'giro',
  secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: { secure: false },
  maxAge: process.env.SESSION_EXPIRY,
  resave: false
}))
app.use(express.json())
app.use(cors())

app.post('/join', subscribeValidator, function (req, res) {
  /*
  if(session.loggedIn) {
    return res.send(JSON.stringify({
      redirect: '/surveys'
    }))
  }
  */

  const data = {
    firstname: req.body.firstname,
    surname: req.body.surname,
    email: req.body.email,
    birthday: req.body.birthday,
    gender: req.body.gender,
    isSubscribed: req.body.isSubscribed
  }

  const errors = validationResult(req.body)
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.status(422).json({ errors: errors.array() })
  }

  open
    .then(conn => conn.createChannel())
    .then(ch => ch
      .assertQueue('subscribe')
      .then(ok => {
        ch.sendToQueue('subscribe', Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(data)))

        req.session.firstname = data.firstname
        req.session.email = data.email
        req.session.isSubscribed = data.isSubscribed
        req.session.confirmed = false
        req.session.loggedIn = true

        req.session.save()
        res.send(JSON.stringify({
          redirect: '/surveys',
          firstname: data.firstname,
          email: data.email
        }))
      })
    )
    .catch(console.warn)
})

app.post('/surveys', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.session.loggedIn)
  if (!req.session.loggedIn) {
    return res.send(JSON.stringify({
      error: {
        type: 'auth',
        message: 'You must be logged in to view and complete surveys. Have you signed up?'
      }
    }))
  }

  res.send(JSON.stringify({
    surveys: [
      'one',
      'two',
      'three'
    ]
  }))
})

// Start the server :)
app.listen(3000, () => 
  console.log('Server running at: http://localhost:3000')
)
```

I've checked many SO posts which don't relate to my problem, read the docs over and over, but I still seem to be missing something.

Thanks

Comment: What is the client?  Browser?  Or some other programmatic request?

Comment: Client is a browser.

Comment: Are these routes regular browser requests?  Or are these ajax calls?  I see you are enable CORs.  Are these requests coming from a web page at a different domain than this host?  Have you looked in the browser to see if the desired session cookie is there?  Have you logged the cookie on the server to see if the desired cookie is there?  You can go to the network tab in the Chrome debugger to see everything the client is sending and receiving from the server (including cookies) for any given request.

Comment: The cookie is encrypted but yes the cookie is present in the browser. The requests are being made on `locahost:1313`, and the api is on `localhost:3000`. I'm able to make requests to and from the API without issues but I hadn't considered CORS being an issue here with cookies.

Comment: Do one of the following.  Look at the network tab in the browser and see if the cookie is being sent to the server with a given request OR log the value of the cookies upon receiving a given request on the server.  You need to first establish whether the browser is or isn't sending the cookies to the server. Looking at the network tab in the browser will also show you whether the browser thinks it has to do pre-flight or not with an OPTIONS request and what it is getting back from that.

Comment: I think I see the problem. The cookies are not present on the `1313` host. My guess is now that because the request is coming from `1313` no cookies are being sent with the request.

Comment: Solved it. Thank you for your help. Without it I would have never have thought to look at cors. TIL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of @jfriend00 I was able to solve the problem. Because the API was on a different port from the CDN that was making the request it falls under a cross origin request when making an `xhr` request from the CDN to the API. Although I had `cors` enabled in order for cookies to work cross origin you have to make a few tweaks.

First of all I had to configure `express-cors` like so:

```
app.use(cors({
  origin: 'http://localhost:1313',
  credentials: true
}))
```

This sets the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header value to `http://localhost:1313`. Wildcards can not be used otherwise it will fail the pre-flight check.

The `crednetials` property sets the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` header value to `true`. Again, pre flight will fail without this.

When making requests on the host I also had to use `withCredentials`. I'm using superagent so I did it like so:

```
componentDidMount () {
    request
      .post('http://localhost:3000/surveys')
      .withCredentials()
      .set('accept', 'json')
      .end((err, res) => {
        this.setState({ isLoading: false })
        ...
      })
}
```

And now it works :)

Comment: Thanks, added `withCredentials`(`credentials:"include"`) and now the session is persisting.

Answer (score 0):

On express: when we use `cors`, we put:

```
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    credentials: true,
  })
);
```

And on client side: with each `axios` request, we put:

```
const res = await axios.get(url, {withCredentials: true})
```